# Replace content of Kendo ObservableArray without event firing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI grid with data in an ObservableArray.

```
var aKendoObservableArray = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([ .....]);

// defining the grid ....
dataSource: {
                data: aKendoObservableArray,
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "_jobInstanceId" // the identifier of the model
                    }
                }
            },
```

I want to replace the content of this array now that I have gotten new data from the server. I have tried splicing the array to clear it and add new content one by one. This causes a huge performance drop since kendo try to determine on every addition how to paginate the grid. Is there a way that I can replace the content of a Kendo UI ObservableArray with the change event firing only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KendoUI forum has an answer to this question. We need to clean the array (one remove event fired) and push all the elements at once (one add event fired)

http://www.telerik.com/forums/passing-array-to-observablearray-push

Thus, what I need would be

```
// clean the array
aKendoObservableArray.splice(0, aKendoObservableArray.length);
aKendoObservableArray.push.apply(aKendoObservableArray, [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this is what I had to do to remove an item:

```
var idToRemove = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

// remove all items that do not share the ID the user is trying to delete
for (var i = 0; i < e.model.MyArrayOfItems.length; i++) {
    if (e.model.MyArrayOfItems[i].idToMatch == idToRemove)
        e.model.MyArrayOfItems.splice(i, 1);
}
```